# Finding Quantile Function from CDF

Tags: statistics, quantile, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Let $f\left( x \right) = {{\left( {1 + \alpha x} \right)} \over 2}$
>   for $ - 1 \le x \le 1$, and $0$ otherwise. We further assume that
>   $\left| \alpha  \right| < 1$. Show that (i) $f$ is a density, (ii)
>   find the cumulative distribution $F$ and (iii) the quantile function $Q$.

My attempt:

Items (i) and (ii) were straightforward.

(i) I showed that $$\int\limits_{ - 1}^1 {{{\left( {1 + \alpha x} \right)} \over 2}} dx = {1 \over 2}\left( 2 \right) + {1 \over 4}\left( {1 - 1} \right) = 1$$
so $f$ is a density indeed.

(ii) I found $F$ by doing $$\int\limits_{ - 1}^x {{{\left( {1 + \alpha t} \right)} \over 2}dt}  = F\left( x \right) = {1 \over 4}\left( {\alpha {x^2} + 2x + 2 - \alpha } \right)$$

*Until here, both answers match the final answers, which were provided.*

(iii) Regarding the quantile function, I can't finish my attempt. Knowing that the quantile function is the inverse of the CDF, I wrote ${1 \over 4}\left( {\alpha {x^2} + 2x + 2 - \alpha } \right) = y$ and tried soving for $x$ in order to find a $F(p)=x$.
$$\eqalign{
  & \alpha {x^2} + 2x + \left( {2 - \alpha  - 4y} \right) = 0  \cr 
  & \Delta  = {b^2} - 4ac = 4 - 8\alpha  + 4{\alpha ^2} + 16\alpha y \cr} $$

I knew this delta would be problematic and I couldn't go past this point:
$$\eqalign{
  & x = {{ - b \pm \sqrt \Delta  } \over {2a}}  \cr 
  & {x_1} = {{ - 2 + \sqrt {4 - 8\alpha  + 4{\alpha ^2} + 16\alpha y} } \over {2\alpha }}  \cr 
  & {x_2} = {{ - 2 - \sqrt {4 - 8\alpha  + 4{\alpha ^2} + 16\alpha y} } \over {2\alpha }} \cr} $$

I don't know if there's anyway I can "ignore" one of the $x's$ based on given conditions, or if this is not the way to go at all. The final answer is supposed to be $Q\left( \beta  \right) = 2\beta  - 1$ if $\alpha  = 0$ and $Q\left( \beta  \right) = {1 \over \alpha }\left( { - 1 + \sqrt {{\alpha ^2} + 4\alpha \beta  - 2\alpha  + 1} } \right)$ if $\alpha  \ne 0$. (I'm not even sure I got this beta notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that one of the roots of the quadratic isn't even in $[-1,1]$. Evidently the root that is in $[-1,1]$ is the one you called $x_1$, indeed their solution agrees with your $x_1$ once you cancel out a factor of $2$.